# Can I get USA tourist visa from within Pakistan during this covid period in 2021?

Tags: visas, usa, pakistan, tourism

Can I get a USA tourist visa from within Pakistan in 2021? And how much time will it take to get the visa stamped?

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, no, you can not apply for such a visa from within Pakistan.

The US embassy and consulates in Pakistan [are currently only processing visa applications for these categories](https://pk.usembassy.gov/visas/):

> - Immigrant visa applicants who are spouses and children of U.S. citizens
> - F, M, certain J categories (alien physician, government visitor, international visitor professor, research scholar, short-term research scholar, specialist, secondary school student and college/university student)
> - I (media and journalism) category
> - Petition-based work visas: (H1B, H2B, L, O, P, Q, and R categories) not subject to [Presidential Proclamation 10052](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/extension-of-presidential-proclamations-10014-and-10052.html).  Exceptions to Presidential Proclamation 10052 are listed [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/proclamation-suspending-entry-of-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-who-present-risk-to-the-US-labor-market-during-the-economic-recovery-following-the-COVID-19-outbreak.html).

Tourist visas are ["nonimmigrant" B-2 visas](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) and are not presently included in this list.

Depending on the course of the covid-19 pandemic, things may change later in the year. You should keep an eye on the [Embassy's website](https://pk.usembassy.gov/visas/) for updates.